# Mosquitto MQTT Websocket works with localhost but Not with IP address

Tags: websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I have Mosquitto broker v2.0.14 running on local machine (windows 11). My config file is

```
listener 1883 
protocol mqtt

listener 9001
protocol websockets
allow_anonymous true
```

Broker starts

```
C:\Program Files\mosquitto>mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf
1657343153: mosquitto version 2.0.14 starting
1657343153: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
1657343153: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1657343153: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1657343153: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
1657343153: mosquitto version 2.0.14 running
```

My java script code is

```
var mqtt;
        var recontime = 2000;
        var host = "192.168.0.107";
        var port = 9001;
        function onConnect() {

            console.log("Connected");
            mqtt.subscribe("/Temp");
        
        }
```

I get error message
'mqttws31.min.js:36 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9001/mqtt' failed '

**It connects when I replace the IP address with localhost in the java script.**

I have tried adding the IP address after listener 9001 but no effect.

I have read through various posts but not getting a clue.
Even telnet is not opening the port (when broker is running)

Comment: Have you made sure that port 9001 is open in the firewall?

Comment: Yes. I also tried after disabling the firewall. Works fine with localhost but not with IP even 127.0.0.1

Comment: One more observation. If I add IP address after the listener, even local host fails to connect. Does it mean that the listener is bound to the IP?. When I bind 0.0.0.0 as the IP localhost works but not '127.0.0.1'  or the IP of the system

Comment: Adding an address to the end of the `listener` lines will bind to that address. I suggest you try using `netstat` to see exactly what is bound (edit the question with the output)

Comment: netstat is not showing port 9001

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer in [github](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2628)
Mosquitto will not bind both IPv4 and IPv6 for Websockets, you need to specify ipv4, configuration: socket_domain ipv4
It is worth noting that I try to configure before the listener, the service fails to start.
socket_domain ipv4 must be configured after listener
Summary: try to configure socket_domain ipv4 after listener and protocol

```
listener 1883
listener 8883
protocol websockets
socket_domain ipv4
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange but it worked. I was using ver 2.0.14. **When I down versioned to 2.0.9a, it started connecting**